# Get first tweet of a given day

Tags: twitter

Hi all 
  I am new to twitter API.. So my question may be a trivial one..

I am developing a new twitter widget, in which I want to get the first tweet for a given hashtag on a particular date.

say first tweet for #xyz hashtag tweeted on 12-08-10.

so far through googling and api doc I found rpp * page max  = 1500.. if totaltweet for a given day is 2000 how can I retrieve last 500 tweets..

Answer (score 0):

I have a few questions?
1. Is this for any hashtag that a user might request on the fly, or a set of hashtags that generally remain the same?

1. If it is a set of tags that stays the same for a while, roughly how many tags are there?
2. When you say a particular date, how far back in time are you going?

There are two standard ways to get tweets for a hashtag. You can use search, which goes back around 7 days or 1,500 tweets. For an active tag, that may only be a day or two. You can use the streaming API, but that doesn't go back, it just starts tracking from the moment you start making the request. The streaming API can track up to 400 hashtags without getting approval for a higher rate. The search API is limited to 10 to 20 hashtags per query.

If you answer questions 1-3, I can suggest a path to getting what you want.

Comment: 1.user may set any hashtags on fly 2. only one at any point of time 3. mostly the current date

Comment: I realize that there is one more question. After the user provides the hashtag, are you supposed to go back in time and show the first hashtag at the previous midnight or the next midnight.

Comment: If you need to go back to the previous midnight, the only answer is to use the search API. One hashtag will not be a problem in that case. You can use the cursor argument to go back in time up to 1,500 tweets. That should work for most single tags. For future days you can set a cron job to collect search results just after midnight.